# Keep exiting activity on top in activity transition

Tags: android, android-activity, android-transitions

I am doing a translate activity transition using `overridePendingTransition()` where the incoming activity (say A) is already partly on the screen, but behind the exiting activity (say B). When the transition starts, A immediately comes above B, covering some part of it. I want it to stay below B and get uncovered as B moves away. How can I accomplish that? Also, how can I get a method to trigger when the transition ends, like it does in `onAnimationEnd()` of `AnimatorListener`.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Did you find the answer? 
I've created similar question: [Two levels of activities on Android. Seamless transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130417/two-levels-of-activities-on-android-seamless-transition)